# Should chatGPT created answers be banned on this site?

Tags: discussion

I recently noticed that a user posted a number of ChatGPT generated answers. Such answers are often vague and fail to answer the questions that were asked (and they don’t mention the use of ChatGPT).

Without any attribution to [chatGPT](https://openai.com/blog/chatgpt/) they probably count as plagiarism by Stack Exchange rules.

Should we ban ChatGPT answers outright on Personal Finance & Money?

Note that Stack Overflow has [a help centre article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy) describing its ban on chatGPT answers that is likely worth a read. On Stack Overflow such answers are deleted by moderators on receipt of a custom flag, is that the way moderators want to proceed here too?

Comment: Thank you for posting this, after the recent answers were flagged I was planning on doing it myself but hadn't had time yet. I've posted my preferred option for voting, but of course others can post the opposite view if they wish.

Comment: What are some example posts? Do they happen to relate to car insurance?

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea I hadn't realised that the user posting them had actually started spamming too, which actually makes dealing with chatGPT itself less urgent as that particular user can just be removed. But now the discussion has started I'd still rather just say it's banned.

Comment: Fight fire with fire - Make ChatGPT a moderator and train it not to accept content from itself.  On second thought, that might be the thing that sets skynet on a path to destroy humans.

Comment: It would also be cool to give chatgpt an (anonymous?) account and answer x number of questions per day, and then see how well it does.

Comment: @Aequitas User's on Stack Overflow essentially tried just pasting in ChatGPT answers for some weeks when it first came out. They are extremely non-specific and often simply wrong. My expectation is that the account would be answer banned in fairly short order if it was tried here. We have already had a couple of ChatGPT answers on Money that were exactly like that although they are now deleted. Those answers prompted this Meta post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, I think we should ban them.

EDIT: I have [now done so](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3082/use-of-chatgpt-and-other-ai-generators-is-banned). Of course the policy can continue to be debated and revised/revoked in future if appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

Yes they should be banned, the problem isn’t whether or not chatgpt can produce “good” answers, sometimes it can other times it can’t, the problem really is that when it’s the latter it’s too much of a clean-up effort for the moderators.

Answer (score -5):

No. We should allow them. If ChatGPT produces a good answer, I would like to see it.