# Use of chatGPT and other AI generators is banned

Tags: support

### Use of text generated by ChatGPT or other AI generation tools is banned for now.

For now, the use of ChatGPT or other AI generation tools to create posts here on Personal Finance & Money is not permitted. If a user is believed to have used them after the posting of this temporary policy, sanctions will be imposed to prevent them from continuing to post such content, even if the posts would otherwise be acceptable.

For more background, see:

- the [network-wide discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384396/ban-chatgpt-network-wide)
- the [Help Center article on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)
- the [initial discussion on Personal Finance & Money Meta](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3080/should-chatgpt-created-answers-be-banned-on-this-site)

Comment: Any chance we could add the new banner described at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395881/sites-can-now-request-to-enable-a-banner-to-warn-about-their-policy-on-ai-genera?cb=1 ?

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea feel free to start the discussion mentioned in the "How can I enable this on my site" - I'd be in favour, I just haven't had time to kick that off myself.

Comment: Ok, I posted [here](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3129/should-we-enable-the-new-banner-that-warns-about-our-sites-policy-on-ai-generat).

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for being proactive on this - I noticed this account https://money.stackexchange.com/users/121905/frugalfinancecl had a lot of answers that were, IMO, deceitfully confident about pretty bland material, writing in a way that seems verrrrry AI-based.

Frankly I think personal finance is one of the more dangerous areas to allow ChatGPT or other AI answering. You can already find answers by that user and others giving concrete recommendations for portfolio mixes, etc..

Someone could say "anyone can write an answer like that", but frankly the idea of such an answer being written by someone who couldn't even type the drivel themselves, makes me concerned about how deep someone could tread, completely out of their element.

Answer (score 1):

One of a number of tools to use is [this AI detector](https://contentatscale.ai/ai-content-detector/?fpr=penguin).

The member Grade Eh linked shows as sub 40% probability written by a human. There are a number of these tools available, we might need to start using them and flagging those who violate the no-AI rules.

Comment: The company that provides that tool is an AI content company, which advertises being able to create content that is undetectable as AI-produced. In my opinion, that makes this particular tool very suspect. Certainly, the motives of the company behind it are biased.

Comment: Have you tried running any of your own answers through it? I ran a few of my most recent answers through it, and the “worst” one got a 25% human content score. I can assure you that, although it was probably not the best answer I’ve ever written, it was 100% written by my fully human self. :)

Comment: Lol, yes. I ran 3, and got scores 96,98,100. To your first comment, this was just a sample, I’m hopeful we, as a community, would find others that are more accurate and are motive-free.