# Should we enable the new banner that warns about our site's policy on AI-generated content?

Tags: feature-request, status-review

First, please see:

- [Meta StackExchange - Sites can now request to enable a banner to warn about their policy on AI-generated content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395881/sites-can-now-request-to-enable-a-banner-to-warn-about-their-policy-on-ai-genera).

Is the *Money* community interested in opting in to displaying one of the proposed warnings? We have had some new users coming here and posting AI-generated content, for a variety of inauthentic reasons. The warning may help avoid some of these types of posts. The options available are:

- **Reminder**: Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools are not allowed on Personal Finance & Money. [Learn more]
- **Reminder**: Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools must be cited on Personal Finance & Money. [Learn more]

Also, re:

> Both options have a "Learn more" link, which will point to a per-site
> help center article, whose contents should also be a part of the
> community discussion — this article should explain what the site's
> policy on AI-generated content is [...]

Is our [existing meta post "Use of chatGPT and other AI generators is banned for now"](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3082/use-of-chatgpt-and-other-ai-generators-is-banned) sufficient in describing the current policy, or do we need new text?

Comment: I only just noticed that the link needs to point to a Help Center article, not just a meta post. We need to draft that, then.

Comment: if people are only using ai assisted content deliberately for inauthentic reasons, I don't see how having the banner would stop them

Comment: It looks like there might be some central drafting happening: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396626/proposed-changes-to-help-center-articles-to-include-mention-of-ai-generated-cont

Comment: I've marked this for CM attention according to the instructions [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348642/what-posts-should-be-escalated-to-staff-using-status-review-and-how-do-i-esca) which I think should mean that they will act on the consensus here in favour of disallowing AI answers.

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica Thank you!

Comment: Help center article is now live: https://money.stackexchange.com/help/ai-policy - I think the banner is coming soon.

Answer (score 13):

Creating an answer so we can vote on it.

I'd be in favour of:

> Reminder: Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools are not allowed on Personal Finance & Money. [Learn more]

with the link pointing to [Use of chatGPT and other AI generators is banned](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3082/use-of-chatgpt-and-other-ai-generators-is-banned)

Comment: I agree with "not allowed".  Just requesting citation opens a can of worms.